# Slide-Game in Swing

Tags: java, game, swing

This was done as an assignment in school. As I am still learning some of the basic parts of Java be ***merciless*** when it comes to my code. As it is an assignment, some things are unchangeable. The specification requires:

- `Swing`. So no third-party library is allowed.
- `Cell` class with `getCol()` and `getRow()` methods.
- For the final product to be a Slide-Game.

[image: Slide game]

Some extra features that I tried to implement in a good way.

- Dyanmic handle for rows and cols. It should work for anything over 2 rows and 2 cols.
- Victory check and click tracker.

**GUI.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GUI implements ActionListener
{
    public static final int WINDOW_MIN_X = 240;
    public static final int WINDOW_MIN_Y = 200;

    public static final int COLS = 4;
    public static final int ROWS = 4;
    public static final int HGAP = 3;
    public static final int VGAP = 3;

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_CELLS = ROWS * COLS;

    private JFrame frame;
    private List<Cell> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Cell> correct = new ArrayList<>();
    private Cell emptyButton;

    private int movesCounter;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class GUI
     */
    public GUI ()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Slide Game");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension (WINDOW_MIN_X, WINDOW_MIN_Y));

        frame.setLayout (new GridLayout (ROWS, COLS, HGAP, VGAP));

        for( Integer i = NUMBER_OF_CELLS-1; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
            createCell (i);
        }

        emptyButton = buttons.get (NUMBER_OF_CELLS-1);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

        setVictoryCondition ();
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if (checkNeighbour((Cell)e.getSource())) {
            swap ((Cell)e.getSource());
            movesCounter++;
            checkVictory ();
        } else {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }

    /**
     * createCell (String s)
     * 
     * Creates a Cell and adds an ActionListener
     * 
     * @param   String s
     */
    private void createCell (int v) {
        Cell c = new Cell (v);
        c.addActionListener(
            (ActionEvent e) -> {actionPerformed(e);}
        );
        buttons.add(c);
        frame.add(c);
    }

    /**
     * checkNeighbour (Cell c)
     * 
     * Checks if c is within 1 grid of emptyButton (non-diagonal)
     * 
     * @param   Cell c
     * 
     * @return false if c is more than one grid away from emptyButton
     */
    private boolean checkNeighbour (Cell c) {
        int x = Math.abs(c.getCol() - emptyButton.getCol());
        int y = Math.abs(c.getRow() - emptyButton.getRow());

        if (!(x == 0 && y == 1 || y == 0 && x == 1)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * swap (Cell c)
     * 
     * Swaps c with emptyButton
     * 
     * @param   Cell c
     */
    private void swap (Cell c) {
        // swap c and empty
        String tmp = emptyButton.getText ();
        emptyButton.setText (c.getText ());
        c.setText (tmp);

        // update reference to empty button
        emptyButton = c;
    }

    /**
     * setVictoryCondition ()
     * 
     * Initiates correct list
     */
    private void setVictoryCondition () {
        for (Integer i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_CELLS; i++) {
            correct.add (new Cell (i));
        }
        correct.add(new Cell (0));
    }

    /**
     * checkVictory ()
     * 
     * Compares buttons to correct lists, if match declare victory!
     */
    private void checkVictory () {        
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CELLS; i++) {
            if (!(buttons.get(i).getText ().equals( correct.get(i).getText ()))) {
                return;
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You achieved victory in " + movesCounter + " moves.",
            "Congratulations!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

**Cell.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cell extends JButton
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8822510600483479089L;
    private int row;
    private int col;

    public Cell (Integer value)
    {
        if (value == 0) {
            setText (" "); 
        } else {
            setText(value.toString());
        }

        row = GUI.NUMBER_OF_CELLS / GUI.COLS-1 - ( value / GUI.COLS);
        col = GUI.NUMBER_OF_CELLS-1 - (row*GUI.COLS + value);

    }

    public int  getCol (){
        return col;
    }

    public int getRow (){
        return row;
    }
}
```

In short, the code is working. I am fairly happy with the result. I wonder if (and if so where) there are room for improvements.

Answer (score 6):

#### Cell class

```
public class Cell extends JButton
```

I would not `extend` JButton. It is better to use composition/encapsulation and store a `JButton` *inside* the `Cell` class. Right now you can call plenty of `JButton` methods from outside the `Cell` class that is totally irrelevant to the `Cell` itself. Just check the [many inherited methods that a JButton has!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)

---

```
if (!(buttons.get(i).getText ().equals( correct.get(i).getText ())))
```

No need to wrap it in an extra set of parenthesis, and please watch your spacing.

```
if (!buttons.get(i).getText().equals(correct.get(i).getText()))
```

However, when you apply the advice above and encapsulate the `JButton` inside the `Cell` class, you can use something like this in your `Cell` class:

```
int getNumber() {
    return this.number;
}

void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
    this.button.setText(number == 0 ? " " : String.valueOf(number));
}
```

If you are unsure about that `a ? b : c` syntax. You can also use an if-else statement:

```
    if (number == 0) {
        this.button.setText(" ");
    } else {
        this.button.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    }
```

---

```
public Cell (Integer value)
```

You are using `Integer` instead of `int` in your entire program. You can use a primitive `int` instead, which is preferred.

---

```
row = GUI.NUMBER_OF_CELLS / GUI.COLS-1 - ( value / GUI.COLS);
col = GUI.NUMBER_OF_CELLS-1 - (row*GUI.COLS + value);
```

You are making your `Cell` dependent on your GUI here. This is generally a bad idea. I would instead pass the `row` and `col` to the `Cell` as constructor arguments.

#### GUI class

```
if (!(x == 0 && y == 1 || y == 0 && x == 1)) {
    return false;
}
```

"If not x equals zero and y equals one or y equals 0 and x equals one." Please don't have me read that again.

I would add extra parenthesis around `x == 0 && y == 1` to avoid mixing up `&&` and `||`.

Also, by switching the logic around it becomes this, which is clearer:

```
if ((x == 0 && y == 1) || (y == 0 && x == 1)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

This can be rewritten to:

```
return (x == 0 && y == 1) || (y == 0 && x == 1);
```

Which is the same as:

```
return x + y == 1;
```

Ain't some math beautiful? :)

---

```
c.addActionListener(
    (ActionEvent e) -> {actionPerformed(e);}
);
```

+1 for using Lambdas! You can write this as:

```
c.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);
```

Comment: `public class Cell extends JButton` was in the specification sorry, should have made that more clear. However I now know for the future. I do know about `a ? b : c` and tried to make use of it. I was using an Integer to have direct access to `Integer.toString()`. Passing arguments to Cell - Check. Fair enough. `return x + y == 1;` that just looks like magic to me.

Comment: @Emz Tell the specification that it is a bad idea like that! By using `String.valueOf()` you don't need to use `Integer.toString()`. `return x + y == 1` is mathematics, not magic ;) It will return `true` whenever the sum of x and y equals to 1, which is essentially what you are checking for.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg `return x + y == 1;` _not_ the same as `return (x == 0 && y == 1) || (y == 0 && x == 1);`. In the first case `x = -4, y = 5` will yield true, in the second case false.

Comment: Never mind, the x and y values were `Math.abs`ed.

Answer (score 6):

You're off to a good start! 
The code is nicely written,
easily readable, simple and it works.
Here are a couple of tips though, on top of @Simon's excellent review.

#### Victory condition

It's odd that you're using a second list of cells to check the victory condition.
It's especially strange that you don't reuse the original cells,
but create a fresh new set of cells,
and perform the check by comparing the output of `getText`.
This last point is especially bad,
because button labels are not designed to be logical elements of the program,
only visualization (hence their type, `String`).

A better way would be to give the `Cell` class an explicit value field,
and check the victory condition using that,
instead of the extra set of buttons and the `getText` method,
for example:

```
private void checkVictory() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CELLS - 1; i++) {
        if (buttons.get(i).getValue() != i + 1) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

This also means that when swapping a cell with the empty cell,
you also need to swap the values:

```
    int value = c.getValue();
    c.setValue(emptyButton.getValue());
    emptyButton.setValue(value);
```

It's a bit of extra work, but I think it's worth it.

#### Naming

Instead of `checkNeighbour`, a more common way to name a method that returns a boolean is to replace "check" with "is". 
This will intuitively distinguish it from other methods that check something without returning a value, such as `checkVictory`.

#### Other minor improvements

Make `final` member variables as much as possible. For example these in `GUI`:

```
private final JFrame frame;
private final List<Cell> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Cell> correct = new ArrayList<>();
```

And these in `Cell`:

```
private final int row;
private final int col;
```

Comment: janos, forgot about the `final` keyword. Just inexperience from my side. I did that way in victoryCheck if someone wanted to add a specific pattern instead of having the simple 1234,5678...

Comment: You can still use specific patterns, by putting the numbers in a list, and compare `buttons.get(i).getValue()` with `correct.get(i)` instead of `i + 1` as in the example I gave you