# Desktop notifications for queue items

Tags: javascript, stackexchange, rags-to-riches, userscript

I wasn't satisfied with Simon's alert on the orange alert. I wanted to know if even 1 review item was available, so I made some modifications to the userscript so that it runs on the Review page, and only alerts you when there are reviews that show a positive number.

[This](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97268/desktop-notifications-for-flags-and-queue-items) is Simon's version, and here is my version:

```
/** @preserve
// ==UserScript==
// @name Review Queue Notification
// @author Malachi Edited Simon Forsberg Created
// @description Shows a desktop notification when there review items in the queue.
// @namespace https://github.com/Zomis/SE-Scripts
// @grant GM_getValue
// @grant GM_setValue
// @grant GM_notification
// @match *://*.stackexchange.com/review*
// @match *://*.stackoverflow.com/review*
// @match *://*.superuser.com/review*
// @match *://*.serverfault.com/review*
// @match *://*.askubuntu.com/review*
// @match *://*.stackapps.com/review*
// @match *://*.mathoverflow.net/review*
// ==/UserScript==
*/

var KEY_NEXT = 'NextReload';
var DELAY = 60 * 1000; //60,000 milliseconds
var currentTime = Date.now ? Date.now() : new Date().getTime();
var lastTime = GM_getValue(KEY_NEXT, 0);
var nextTime = currentTime + DELAY;
GM_setValue(KEY_NEXT, nextTime);

var timeDiff = Math.abs(lastTime - currentTime);
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(); 
}, DELAY);

var title = document.title.split(' - '); // keep the site name
document.title = 'Desktop Notifications - ' + title[1];

// a way to detect that the script is being executed because of an automatic script reload, not by the user.
if (timeDiff <= DELAY * 2) {
    var notifications = [];

    var reviewCount = 0;
    var reviewItems = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard-num');

    for (var i = 0; i < reviewItems.length; i++){
        reviewCount += parseInt((reviewItems[i].getAttribute("title")).replace(',',''), 10);
        console.log(reviewItems[i]);
    }
    console.log(reviewCount);
    if (reviewCount > 0) {
        notifications.push(reviewCount + ' Review Items');
    }

    if (notifications.length) {
        var details = {
            title: document.title,
            text: notifications.join('\n'),
            timeout: 0
        };
        GM_notification(details, null);
    }
}
```

---

<s>This is also available on my GitHub as a [userscript](https://github.com/malachi26/SE-Scripts/blob/master/moderator-tools/ReviewQueueNotification.js).</s>

[Follow-up question with new GitHub repo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105615/desktop-notifications-for-queue-items-updated-code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is mostly personal preference, but, I usually stack the `@match`es  in descending size:

> ```
> // @match *://*.stackexchange.com/review*
> // @match *://*.stackoverflow.com/review*
> // @match *://*.superuser.com/review*
> // @match *://*.serverfault.com/review*
> // @match *://*.askubuntu.com/review*
> // @match *://*.stackapps.com/review*
> // @match *://*.mathoverflow.net/review*
> ```

into:

```
// @match *://*.stackexchange.com/review*
// @match *://*.stackoverflow.com/review*
// @match *://*.mathoverflow.net/review*
// @match *://*.serverfault.com/review*
// @match *://*.askubuntu.com/review*
// @match *://*.stackapps.com/review*    
// @match *://*.superuser.com/review*
```

Just looks nicer, I suppose.

---

`var title = document.title.split(' - ');`:

You don't use `title` for anything other than `title[1]`, so just use `var title = document.title.split(' - ')[1]` instead.

---

`.replace(',','')`: You should have a space after `','`.

---

You could consider replacing the `.length` style `for` loop with a `for (var i in reviewItems)` style loop. If not, you can also declare `reviewCount` in the `for` loop like: `for (var reviewCount = 0, i = 0;`.

---

```
var details = {
        title: document.title,
```

`Desktop Notifications - Code Review Stack Exchange` sounds a little bulky and over-the-top. `Review Items` is a better name for it, and you could consider removing `Stack Exchange`, but, consider the effect that would have on MSE.

---

I can't see the point in using `notifications` as an array, as it should really just have the one notification.

> ```
> if (reviewCount > 0) {
>     notifications.push(reviewCount + ' Review Items');
> }
> if (notifications.length) {
>     var details = {
>         text: notifications.join('\n'),
> ```

```
if (reviewCount > 0) {
    notification = reviewCount + ' Review Items';
}
if (notification) {
    var details = {
        text: notification,
```

or even just move `reviewCount + ' Review Items'` into `details`, like:

```
if (reviewCount > 0) {
    var details = {
        text: reviewCount + ' Review Items',
```

---

As of ECMAScript 5, the default radix used in [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is supposed to be \$10\$, before that, \$0\$ would get parsed as a octal number instead of a decimal number, and, as it seems, you can just omit that optional `radix` argument entirely. Although, as @EthanBierlein pointed out in the comments; MDN recommends not to omit it.

Comment: While you can omit the `radix` argument from `parseInt`, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) doesn't reccomend omitting it.

Comment: In JavaScript, while you can use `for in` for iterating through an array, it is very uncommon, and therefore confusing to the reader.

Comment: Normally, I'd suggest `forEach`, but, it's an object, so the closest alternate to that is `.each` in jQuery, and also why I only presented it as an alternate solution, rather than expounding on it.

Answer (score 3):

Removing some of the code where this would refresh, I forgot to alter the `@match`'s and this made it kind of tricky to do a review (I changed the timer to 20 seconds)

I needed to remove the wildcard from the end

like this

```
// @match *://*.stackexchange.com/review
// @match *://*.stackoverflow.com/review
// @match *://*.superuser.com/review
// @match *://*.serverfault.com/review
// @match *://*.askubuntu.com/review
// @match *://*.stackapps.com/review
// @match *://*.mathoverflow.net/review
```

---

In addition, I also changed the timeout on the popup, because if I had left the window open and left my computer for some time and there was a review left, it would populate a new popup and never dispose it, it was a PITA to close them all and I would rather check the review page when I get back to my desk than have all those glaring at me.

> ```
> if (notifications.length) {
>     var details = {
>         title: document.title,
>         text: notifications.join('\n'),
>         timeout: 0
>     };
>     GM_notification(details, null);
> }
> ```

became this (*with some changes that @Quill suggested*)

```
if (reviewCount > 0) {
    var details = {
        title: document.title,
        text: reviewCount + ' Review Items',
        timeout: 15000
    }
    GM_notification(details, null);
}
```

and I also changed

> ```
> var title = document.title.split(' - '); // keep the site name
> document.title = 'Desktop Notifications - ' + title[1];
> ```

to this

```
document.title = document.title.split(' - ')[1] + ' Review Queue'; // keep the site name
```

we already know that it is a desktop notification, there is no need to throw it in my face every time.

Comment: Did it ever occur to you that you don't need to change the `document.title` at all?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, I think I actually did think about that once.  last night I was setting up a new repo so I could assign myself issues.