# Desktop Notifications for Queue Items - Updated Code

Tags: javascript, stackexchange, userscript

A while ago I took one of @Simon's scripts and updated it to make it more geared towards normal users (no offense mods) and this [Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98619/desktop-notifications-for-queue-items) was created. But the link to the Github is no longer correct and the code has changed quite a bit to get it to work on Firefox and Chrome (and Opera and IceDragon and Safari).

I would like to know if my code is following UserScript and JavaScript standards and if there is anything that I can do to improve the efficiency of the code itself.

Here is the current *Next* version

```
Notification.requestPermission();

var KEY_NEXT = 'NextReload';
var DELAY =  120 * 1000; //120,000 milliseconds = 2 Minutes
var currentTime = Date.now ? Date.now() : new Date().getTime();
var lastTime = GM_getValue(KEY_NEXT, 0);
var nextTime = currentTime + DELAY;
GM_setValue(KEY_NEXT, nextTime);

var timeDiff = Math.abs(lastTime - currentTime);
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(); 
}, DELAY);

var notificationTitle = (document.title.split(' - ')[1] + ' Review Queue').replace(' Stack Exchange', '.SE');

// a way to detect that the script is being executed because of an automatic script reload, not by the user.
if (timeDiff <= DELAY * 2) {
    var reviewCount = 0;
    var reviewItems = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard-num');


    for (var i = 0; i < reviewItems.length; i++){
        if (reviewItems[i].parentNode.className != 'dashboard-count dashboard-faded'){
            reviewCount += parseInt((reviewItems[i].getAttribute("title")).replace(',', ''), 10);
            console.log(reviewItems[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(reviewCount);

    if (reviewCount > 0) {
        var details = {
            body: reviewCount + ' Review Items',
            icon: 'https://github.com/malachi26/ReviewQueueNotifier/raw/master/Resources/Icon2.jpg'
        } 
        var n = new Notification(notificationTitle, details);
        n.onclick = function(){
            window.focus();
            this.cancel();
        }
        setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 100000); // Magic number is time to notification disappear      
    }
}
```

---

You can follow development or participate in development at Github as well.

[Review Queue Notifier](https://github.com/malachi26/ReviewQueueNotifier)

Comment: Smallish point, but I'd replace that `for` loop with a `forEach`, and replace the embedded `if` statement with a returning guard clause for the case you want to ignore.  This saves you a level of nesting and improves clarity.  If you need old browser support and don't want to include the forEach polyfill, that's a decent recent to keep it as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't actually tested the code, just writing JavaScript from the top of my head. Here's some notable changes:

- Using what I call "return early". That way, it avoids nested `if`s and your code looks flat.
- Renamed a few variables so that they have more meaning, especially `DELAY` which is very generic and because you have 2 timeouts. Long names don't matter, readability should always be considered.
- Instead of using `Math.abs`, why not reverse the equation? Current time is always larger than time in the past. You'll always get a positive value.
- Replaced your loop with `reduce` because it was designed for that, an aggregator of values.
- You can always use the unary `+` as a shorthand for converting strings into numbers. In most cases, it acts similar to `parseFloat`. If the string is potentially not a number, guard yourself with `isNan`.
- Replaced your `currentTime` to just `Date.now()`. By now, browsers should at least be ES5-compliant. Anything less... you still rolling with IE6 or sumthin'?
- Notification title moved down nearer to notification and after the two early-return `if`. That way, you don't actually generate the title if the script bails out on either of the two returns.
- Inlined your notification details object. Assigning to a variable just took up space, only to be used once.

And the end result:

```
Notification.requestPermission();

var KEY_NEXT = 'NextReload';
var NOTIFICATION_AUTODISMISS_TIMEOUT = 100000;
var RELOAD_DELAY =  120 * 1000; //120,000 milliseconds = 2 Minutes

var currentTime = Date.now();
var lastTime = GM_getValue(KEY_NEXT, 0);
var timeDiff = currentTime - lastTime;
var nextTime = currentTime + RELOAD_DELAY;

GM_setValue(KEY_NEXT, nextTime);

setTimeout(window.location.reload, RELOAD_DELAY);

if (timeDiff > RELOAD_DELAY * 2) return;

var reviewItems = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard-num');
var reviewItemsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(reviewItems);
var reviewCount = reviewItemsArray.reduce(function(count, reviewItem){
    return +reviewItem.getAttribute('title').replace(',', '') + count;
}, 0);

if (reviewCount <= 0)  return;

var notificationTitle = (document.title.split(' - ')[1] + ' Review Queue').replace(' Stack Exchange', '.SE');
var n = new Notification(notificationTitle, {
    body: reviewCount + ' Review Items',
    icon: 'https://github.com/malachi26/ReviewQueueNotifier/raw/master/Resources/Icon2.jpg'
});

n.onclick = function(){
    window.focus();
    this.cancel();
};

setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), NOTIFICATION_AUTODISMISS_TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: Nice! How do you feel about including the unit of time in the constants, for example `RELOAD_MILLIS` ?

Comment: @janos Sounds fine, although it's usually implied since JS usually works with milliseconds most of the time (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `Date.now()` all work with milliseconds).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this code. I still consider myself a novice when it comes to Javascript so there were a couple of things I had to look up here, but a very enjoyable read, and a lot of things that make total sense, things that I should have seen and done, but didn't.

Comment: your code doesn't look like it will disregard the queues that are shadowed out, meaning that you cannot access those queues at this time. I can add an if statement inside that function though I think.

Comment: chrome doesn't like your reduce statement, says that it is not a function.

Comment: @Malachi I forgot `reviewItems` wasn't an array. Updated, converting it into an array with `slice`.