# Queue Notifier Extension Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to keep the progression of the Review Queue Notifier moving forward.  My next big move is to turn it into an extension for Chrome and FireFox and eventually Edge.

I would like the Javascript for the code reviewed again to get me back into the groove of coding this extension/script.

Here are the guts:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Public Key
    var publicKey = '?key=hyEwZ8*W*OF7tQ3KYgNjzg((';
    var sites;
    var ACTIVESITES;// = chrome.storage.sync.get(activeSites);

    GetSelectedSites();
    getAllTehSitez();

    function getAllTehSitez() {
        console.log("getAllTehSitez has been called");
        $.getJSON('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites' + publicKey + '&pagesize=100', function(data) {
            sites = data.items;
            isActiveSite();
        });
    }

    function isActiveSite() {
        console.log("isActiveSite has been called");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage("getUrl", function(response) {
            var tabUrl = response.url;
            for (var site in sites) {
                if ((tabUrl == sites[site].site_url + '/review') 
                    && (ACTIVESITES.indexOf(sites[site].name.toLowerCase()) > -1)) {
                        runRQN();
                        return;
                }
            }
        }); 
    }   

    function GetSelectedSites () {
        console.log("GetSelectedSites has been called");
        chrome.storage.sync.get({
            activeSites: "Code Review"
        }, function(item) {
            ACTIVESITES = item.activeSites;
        });
    }

    function runRQN () {
        console.log("runRQN has been called")
        Notification.requestPermission();
        var DELAY =  300 * 1000; //120,000 milliseconds = 2 Minutes
        function getDelayAmount() { 
            chrome.storage.sync.get({
                refreshRate: 300000
            }, function(item){
                DELAY = item.refreshRate;
            });
        }
        getDelayAmount();

        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.reload(); 
        }, DELAY);



        console.log(DELAY);
        var notificationTitle = (document.title.split(' - ')[1] + ' Review Queue').replace(' Stack Exchange', '.SE');
        var reviewCount = 0;
        var reviewItems = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard-num');

        for (var i = 0; i < reviewItems.length; i++){
            if (reviewItems[i].parentNode.className != 'dashboard-count dashboard-faded'){
                reviewCount += parseInt((reviewItems[i].getAttribute("title")).replace(',', ''), 10);
                console.log(reviewItems[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(reviewCount);
        var image = chrome.extension.getURL('Icon2.jpg');
        if (reviewCount > 0) {
            var details = {
                body: reviewCount + ' Review Items',
                icon: image
            } 
            var n = new Notification(notificationTitle, details );
            setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 100000); // Magic number is time to notification disappear      
        }
    }
});
```

[Stack Apps Question](https://stackapps.com/questions/6517/review-queue-desktop-notification-script)

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/malachi26/ReviewQueueNotifier)

This is a follow-up to the following questions, kind of...

[First Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98619/desktop-notifications-for-queue-items)

[Second Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105615/desktop-notifications-for-queue-items-updated-code)

Answer (score 2):

### Foreword

I know that this was posted nearly 1.5 years ago and the code appears to have changed dramatically and perhaps you've already learned about what I will mention below, but I feel like this question needs an answer...

#### Feedback

I like the good use of the Notification interface, as well as the radix passed to `parseInt()`.

#### Suggestions

- The code to check if the site is in the list of active sites, i.e.

  > ```
  > if ((tabUrl == sites[site].site_url + '/review') 
  >             && (ACTIVESITES.indexOf(sites[site].name.toLowerCase()) > -1)) {
  > ```

  can be simplified using [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), which has been supported since FF 43 (released 12/15/2015) and Chrome 47 (released 12/01/2015):

  ```
  if ((tabUrl == sites[site].site_url + '/review') 
              && (ACTIVESITES.includes(sites[site].name.toLowerCase()))) {
  ```
- The reload registration could be simplified from:

  > ```
  > setTimeout(function(){
  >     window.location.reload(); 
  > }, DELAY);
  > ```

  To the following, which makes a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) using [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

  ```
  setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(), DELAY);
  ```

  that way there is no excess lambda/anonymous function, and two fewer lines ([I get the impression you might like one-liners](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/182645/120114))!
- The selection of dashboard elements could be simplified, using a more selective CSS selector:

  > ```
  > var reviewItems = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard-num');
  > for (var i = 0; i < reviewItems.length; i++){
  >     if (reviewItems[i].parentNode.className != 'dashboard-count dashboard-faded'){
  > ```

  Instead, one could utilize the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector and [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (or jQuery selector function, though that would return a jQuery collection instead of a NodeList):

  ```
  var reviewItems = document.querySelectorAll('.dashboard-num:not(.dashboard-count):not(.dashboard-faded)');
  ```
- One could utilize promises for the asynchronous callbacks...