# Wrath Cookie Switch for Auto Golden Cookie Clicker

Tags: javascript, game, functional-programming

Sometimes you feel like a wrath cookie and sometimes you don't.

Here is a function that I created that will run on an interval, so all I have to do is set a boolean when I want to switch between *Wrath + Gold* cookies and just *Gold* cookies.

```
// allows me to turn on and off the clicking of the Wrath Cookies
var wrathCookieSwitchOn = false;

var SpecialCookieClicker =
    setInterval(function() {
        if (wrathCookieSwitchOn){
            Game.shimmers.forEach(function(shimmer) {
                if (shimmer.type == "golden") { shimmer.pop() }
            })
        } else {
            Game.shimmers.forEach(function(shimmer) {
                if(shimmer.type == "golden" && shimmer.wrath == 0)
                {
                    shimmer.pop()
                }
            })
        }
    }, 500);
```

All I have to do is change the variable value in the Developer Console in order to affect this code.

How could I do this a little better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How could I do this a little better?

Initially my eyes are directed at the two branches of the conditional and ways to eliminate the redundancy. Would it be too long of a line to move that conditional check of `wrathCookieSwitchOn` inside the `if` inside the `forEach`?

```
Game.shimmers.forEach(function(shimmer) {
    if (shimmer.type == "golden" && (wrathCookieSwitchOn || shimmer.wrath == 0) { 
        shimmer.pop() 
    }
})
```

It must be asked whether the type of `shimmer.wrath` needs to be an integer. If any falsely value will suffice, then `shimmer.wrath == 0` could be simplified to `!shimmer.wrath`, otherwise, use strict equality: `shimmer.wrath === 0`

Beyond that, the only idea I have possibly removing the closure by some technique like currying or just defining a function... or if ES-2015 is an option, simplify it into an arrow function.

#### Update

In response to [your answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/182645/120114), I shall reveal another option I considered, which some argue might be less readable, but yes, like you typed: “*if we are going to one-line it, let's one-line it!*”:

```
Game.shimmers.forEach(function(shimmer) {
    shimmer.type == "golden" && (wrathCookieSwitchOn || shimmer.wrath == 0) && shimmer.pop();
});
```

Which would lend itself well to an arrow function (if permissible).

Answer (score 5):

I could do it like @Sam says, my style is to use ternary statements though, like this:

```
var SpecialCookieClicker = 
    setInterval(function() {
        Game.shimmers.forEach(function(shimmer) {
            shimmer.type == "golden" && (shimmer.wrath == 0 || wrathCookieSwitchOn) ? shimmer.pop() : 0;
        })
    }, 500);
```

I mean, if we are going to one-line it, let's one-line it!