# Cookie Clicker Switches

Tags: javascript, game, functional-programming, timer

In [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) there are Golden cookies, and Wrath Golden Cookies.

Golden cookies are Clickable cookies that randomly appear, and when clicked they give Bonus cookies, or temporary boosts to clicking/Cookies Per second (i.e. Cps).

The Wrath Golden cookies can still give boosts and bonuses, but they have the chance of taking cookies or giving a reverse boost to Cps.

Wrath Golden Cookies happen as an effect of pushing the Grandmas too far.

Some "power-ups" require Golden cookies to stay on the screen and not be clicked right away, so I wanted a fast way to turn off the clicker.

I came up with a way to turn on and off the Golden/Wrath switches using a single command in the console, and they give a little more information as well.

```
// allows me to turn on and off the clicking of the Wrath Cookies

var wrathCookieSwitchOn = false;
var cookieSwitchOn = false;

var wrathSwitch = function() {
    wrathCookieSwitchOn = !wrathCookieSwitchOn;
    console.log("WrathCookieSwitchOn is set to " + wrathCookieSwitchOn);
}

var flipCookieSwitch = function(){
    cookieSwitchOn = !cookieSwitchOn;
    if (cookieSwitchOn) {
        var SpecialCookieClicker = 
            setInterval(function() {
                Game.shimmers.forEach(function(shimmer) {
                    (shimmer.type == "golden") && (shimmer.wrath == 0 || wrathCookieSwitchOn) ? shimmer.pop() : 0;
                })
            }, 500);
        console.log("Golden Cookie Clicker is on and wrathCookieSwitchOn is set to " + wrathCookieSwitchOn);
    } else {
        clearInterval(SpecialCookieClicker);
        console.log("Golden Cookie Clicker is Turned off");
    }
};
flipCookieSwitch();
```

I was thinking about overloading the function so that I could flip the Wrath Switch as well, but I haven't decided how I want to do that yet.

Does the code make sense to you? Is there anything I could make better or more efficient?

[Link to the Game itself, it is addicting and ***YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED***](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)

<sub>none of the scripts that I have posted here are considered cheating by the game</sub>

Comment: You mean, none of the scripts are detected as cheating by the game. Whether you or other people consider them cheating is a completely separate matter.

Comment: you get an achievement for cheating, I probably should elaborate that...lol. you don't get the achievement for cheating when using these scripts.

Comment: Do you typically run these functions in the console, a bookmark-let and/or a grease monkey script?

Comment: Normally run it via the console. I suppose that you could use a bookmark, but I think it is quicker if you use the console on your second monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Responses

> Does the code make sense to you?

Yes, for the most part. I am still becoming acquainted with the game play and hacks.

> anything I could make better or more efficient?

In general, using an integer 0/1 instead of boolean would lead to faster performance<sup>[1](https://jsperf.com/bool-vs-int/8)</sup>. To change the value, the [bitwise NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT)) (i.e. `~`) can be used. Note that applying NOT on a signed integer will yield -` but that is still a truthy value. While it was asked more than 6 years ago, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7221963/1575353) has some interesting discussion on that matter.

[image]

```js
var wrathCookieSwitchOn = 0;
var cookieSwitchOn = 0;

var wrathSwitch = function() {
  wrathCookieSwitchOn = ~wrathCookieSwitchOn;
  console.log("WrathCookieSwitchOn is set to " + wrathCookieSwitchOn);
}

function checkWrathCookieSwitchOn() {
  if (wrathCookieSwitchOn) {
    console.log('wrathCookieSwitchOn',wrathCookieSwitchOn);
  }
}
wrathSwitch();
checkWrathCookieSwitchOn();
wrathSwitch();
checkWrathCookieSwitchOn();
```

### Other thoughts

#### Ternary vs Short-circuiting logical operators

As I mentioned in [an answer to your previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/182636/120114), the ternary could be simplified from:

> ```
> (shimmer.type == "golden") && (shimmer.wrath == 0 || wrathCookieSwitchOn) ? shimmer.pop() : 0;
> ```

To:

```
(shimmer.type == "golden") && (shimmer.wrath == 0 || wrathCookieSwitchOn) && shimmer.pop();
```

While it only saves about 2 keystrokes, it is essentially like removing an `else` clause from an `if` statement.

#### Variable declaration

The declaration of the timer variable `SpecialCookieClicker` is within the *true* block of the `if` statement. While [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) allows the variable to exist throughout the function, 
"*it is recommended to always declare variables at the top of their scope*"<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)</sup> and then assign the value later (e.g..

```
var flipCookieSwitch = function(){
    var SpecialCookieClicker; //declare here
    cookieSwitchOn = !cookieSwitchOn;
    if (cookieSwitchOn) {
        SpecialCookieClicker = setInterval(/*function */, 500); //assign here
    }
}
```

While it *should* be the case that `SpecialCookieClicker` will always be assigned before the `else` block, it may be wise to guard against the scenario of an undefined value (e.g. due to [cosmic rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Effect_on_electronics)) and ensure it is at least truthy before calling `clearInterval()`.

```
SpecialCookieClicker && clearInterval(SpecialCookieClicker);
```

#### Variable names

The word `On` in variables `wrathCookieSwitchOn` and `cookieSwitchOn` convey the sense that the switch is on when the variable is `true`. Without the word `On` it could still be considered semantically the same - so one could argue that the names could be shortened to `wrathCookieSwitch` and `cookieSwitch` without any loss of semantics

#### ES-6

Presuming you aren't using IE, you should be able to utilize ES-6 features, like [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for values that shouldn't be re-assigned and [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for variables that can change. Then the one-liner for that function to pop shimmers can be simplified with an arrow function:

```
Game.shimmers.forEach((shimmer) => (shimmer.type == "golden") && (shimmer.wrath == 0 || wrathCookieSwitchOn) && shimmer.pop(), 500);
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://jsperf.com/bool-vs-int/8</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting</sub>